# Serializing using multiple files

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a fairly simple question, but with a possibly tough answer.
How would I make my code serialize 2 different lists to a file of their own?

List 1 in file 1 and list 2 in file 2

I know how I should make the code use 1 file for both, but 2 files would be better in my case.

I don't see the use of posting my code, but if someone needs it, just ask ;)

Edit:

The situation I have is as followed:

```
if (File.Exists("accounts.bin"))
{
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize = serializer.DeSerializeObject("accounts.bin");
    accounts = objectToSerialize.Accounts;
}
```

The above is called in the mainclass of the program.

```
public class Serializer
{
    public Serializer()
    {
    }

    public void SerializeObject(string filename, ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize)
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public ObjectToSerialize DeSerializeObject(string filename)
    {
        ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        objectToSerialize = (ObjectToSerialize)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return objectToSerialize;
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class ObjectToSerialize : ISerializable
{
    private ObservableCollection<Account> accounts;
    //private ObservableCollection<Pokémon> pokedex;

    public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts
    {
        get { return this.accounts; }
        set { this.accounts = value; }
    }
    /*public ObservableCollection<Pokémon> Pokedex
    {
        get { return this.pokedex; }
        set { this.pokedex = value; }
    }*/

    public ObjectToSerialize()
    {
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("Accounts", Accounts);
    }
}
```

As you can see I already tried some things, but they didn't work.

Comment: Posting code helps us understand what you are thinking, as well as give us a good spot to write the code that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could answer better if I knew what data was in each list but I'll give a couple of examples.

```
List<string> nsv1 = new List<string> { //pretend this is data };
List<string> nsv2 = new List<string> { //pretend this is data };
File.WriteAllLines(@".\path\to\file1.txt", nsv1);
File.WriteAllLines(@".\path\to\file2.txt", nsv2);
```

If you give me a better idea of what your data is I can provide other ways to format it (like say if it's a `List<int>` rather than `List<string>`) but this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: @M.Schevers oh ha, your code is a lot different than I imagined. I might be able to write an answer later but I'm a little to busy to provide a solution right now.